# max-height and changing color of text

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to get the text of and `h1` tag to change from whitish to blackish.  I am trying to use a `max-height` media query but I get no change.

```css
h1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: hsla(281, 100%, 7%, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
}
@media and(max-height: 400px) {
  h1 {
    color: #222222;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>text<h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `media query` syntax:

```css
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
/** CSS Code **/
}
```

So the `and` only applies if there is a `mediatype`. if not don't use it

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
h1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 4em;
  background-color: hsla(281, 100%, 7%, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
@media (max-height: 400px) {
  h1 {
    color: #222222;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  h1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>text</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't get it to work using max-height, but when I tried using min-height it worked.  Is there any way to use the max-height to change the color of the h1 text if I scroll down past the max-height:400px?  Other than using javascript.

Comment: you have to create another media query, if you don't  want to have the predefined color that you set before media queries.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove "and" like this :

```
@media (max-height: 400px) {
  h1 {
    color: #222222;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
h1 {
color: #222222;
}
}
```

Or if not specifying screen type

```
@media (max-height: 400px) {
h1 {
color: #222222;
}
}
```